# How to get ini file value by key?

Tags: powershell

So i have `ini file` and function that parse my file:

```
Function Parse-IniFile ($file)
{
    $ini = @{}

    # Create a default section if none exist in the file. Like a java prop file.
    $section = "NO_SECTION"
    $ini[$section] = @{}

    switch -regex -file $file
    {
        "^\[(.+)\]$"
        {
            $section = $matches[1].Trim()
            $ini[$section] = @{}
        }

        "^\s*([^#].+?)\s*=\s*(.*)"
        {
            $name,$value = $matches[1..2]

            # skip comments that start with semicolon:
            if (!($name.StartsWith(";")))
            {
                $ini[$section][$name] = $value.Trim()
            }
        }
    }

    $ini
}
```

Usage:

```
$iniFile = Parse-IniFile "myFile.ini"
```

So in case my file contains specific key for example `"blabla"` how can i get the value ?

This is what i have try:

```
$value= $iniFile["blabla"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parsing an INI file produces a hashtable of the sections from the INI file where the value of each section key is another hashtable with the key/value pairs from the respective section.

Basically, an INI file like this:

```
[something]
foo=23
bar=42

[other]
baz=5
```

becomes a hashtable datastructure like this:

```
@{
  'something' = @{
    'foo' = 23
    'bar' = 42
  }
  'other' = @{
    'baz' = 5
  }
}
```

What you need to do to get the value of a particular key in a nested hashtable is to check which nested hashtable contains a key of that name:

```
$iniFile.Keys | Where-Object {
  $iniFile[$_].ContainsKey('blabla')
} | ForEach-Object {
  $iniFile[$_]['blabla']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In chosen hashtable data model, you need to know *section name(s)* to make out *property value(s)* for a given *property key*; this data model is as follows:

```
$y = @{ 'sectionname' = @{ 'propertykey' = 'propertyvalue' } }
```

You could get more straightforward (I dare say *first-hand*) access to *property value(s)* for a given *property key* using **reversed** hashtable **data model**:

```
$x = @{ 'propertykey' = @{ 'sectionname' = 'propertyvalue' } }
```

`Parse-FileIni` function in next script snippet shows possible implementation of the latter (*commented* for better understanding):

```
Function Parse-FileIni ($file)
{
    Function add_ini ( $auxadd )
    {
        if ( -not $ini.ContainsKey($name) )
        {
            $ini[$name] = @{}
        }
        $ini[$name][$section] = $value.Trim()
        if ( $auxadd ) { $aux[$section]++ }
    }
    $ini = @{}                         # create output object
    $aux = @{}                         # create properties counter for sections
    $section = '[]'          # section default name for out-of-sectionproperties

    #switch -regex -file $file         # garbles ANSI characters above 0x7F
                         # works for (plain) ASCII, UTF-8 and files with BOM
    switch -regex ( Get-Content $file )# -Encoding Default (i.e. ANSI)
    {
        '^\[(.+)\]$'                   # [section]
        {
            $section = $matches[1].Trim()
            if ( -not $aux.ContainsKey( $section ) ) {
                $aux[ $section ] = [int] 0
            }

        }

        '^\s*([^#\[;].+?)\s*=\s*(.*)'  # 'name=value'; works as well for 'name='
        {
            $name,$value = $matches[1..2]
            add_ini $true
        }
        '^\s*([^;\[#][^=]+?)$'         # name (omitted '=' or '=value')
        {
            $name = $matches[1].Trim()
            $value = ''
            add_ini $true
        }
    }
    $name,$value = '',''               # add empty sections
    $aux.Keys | ForEach-Object { 
            if ( $aux[$_] -eq 0 ) { 
                $section = $_
                add_ini $false
            }
        }
    $ini                               # return an object
}

Function Parse-IniFile ($file)
{
    $ini = @{}
    # Create a default section if none exist in the file. Like a java prop file.
    $section = "_NO_SECTION"
    $ini[$section] = @{}
    #switch -regex -file $file         
    switch -regex  ( Get-Content $file )
    {
        '^\[(.+)\]$'
        {
            $section = $matches[1].Trim()
            if (-not $ini.ContainsKey($section)) { $ini[$section] = @{} }
        }

        '^\s*([^#\[;].+?)\s*=\s*(.*)'
        {
            $name,$value = $matches[1..2]
            $ini[$section][$name] = $value.Trim()
        }
        '^\s*([^;\[#][^=]+?)$'
        {
            $name = $matches[1].Trim()
            $value = ''
            $ini[$section][$name] = $value.Trim()
        }
    }
    $ini
}

'-iniFile-'

$iniFile = ''
$iniFile = Parse-IniFile "d:\test\Google.ini"
$iniFile | Format-Table -AutoSize -Wrap

'-iniFili-'

$iniFili = ''
$iniFili = Parse-FileIni "d:\test\Google.ini"
$iniFili
```

I made some changes to the original `Parse-IniFile` function necessary to parse my testing `.ini` file correctly; for explanation cf comments in above script and next `Google.ini` file:

```
; PSPad configuration file for Google interface - adapted for testing
;; fake properties out of sections
foo="bar"
bubu=
; Search only pages in selected language
[Language]
Czech=lang_cz
English=lang_en
;; misunderstood (fake) use 
UK=English
; For search use selected Google server
[GoogleServer]
Česká Republika=www.google.cz
Österreich=www.google.at
UK=www.google.co.uk
;; multiple section declaration: simply merge their properties together
[Language]
German=lang_de
;; second occurrence of a property name: discard and override the first occurrence
Czech=lang_cs
;; fake empty section - somewhere in middle
[Client]
; Search only selected server
[ServerSearch]
;; only keys, no values, missing or present =
pspad.com
php.net=
w3.org
;; fake empty section - at the foot of file 
[Protocol]
```

**Output shows the difference**:

```
PS D:\PShell> D:\PShell\SO\41138597_Parse-IniFile.ps1
-iniFile-
Name         Value                            
----         -----                            
_NO_SECTION  {bubu, foo}              
GoogleServer {UK, Česká Republika, Österreich}
Client       {}                               
Language     {English, German, UK, Czech}     
ServerSearch {w3.org, pspad.com, php.net}     
Protocol     {}                               

-iniFili-
Name            Value                   
----            -----                   
bubu            {[]}                    
UK              {GoogleServer, Language}
Czech           {Language}              
w3.org          {ServerSearch}          
php.net         {ServerSearch}          
Österreich      {GoogleServer}          
English         {Language}              
Česká Republika {GoogleServer}          
German          {Language}              
foo             {[]}                    
pspad.com       {ServerSearch}          
                {Client, Protocol}      

PS D:\PShell> $iniFili['UK']
Name                           Value                                                      
----                           -----                                                      
GoogleServer                   www.google.co.uk                                           
Language                       English                                                    

PS D:\PShell> $iniFili['UK']['GoogleServer']
www.google.co.uk
```